# Google Drive is not synchronizing properly

Tags: sync, 15.04, google-drive

I have install `Google Drive` using [this nice tutorial](https://www.thefanclub.co.za/how-to/ubuntu-google-drive-client-grive-and-grive-tools). The issue is the folder is synchronized.

If I choose `Sync Now` option, a synchronization is started and after few seconds a message is displayed that it finished, but  the folder on my `Ubuntu` machine is still empty:

[image]

If I `Open Google Drive on the web` I am seeing the files.

Could anyone advice?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The API for google drive changed so that program won't work anymore.

Comment: Do you know any other alternatives?

Answer (score 2):

After having the fanclub install go dark, I just found this today (6 May) and it installs and runs perfectly.
GRIVE works now.

```
sudo su -c "apt-get install grive-tools"
```

Check this link for details: http://goo.gl/trCAkX
If you have a previous GDrive folder, it will ask if you want to delete and re-create it; your option, but say no and it will use your existing one and re-sync.
In your program finder, search grive and you will see the setup and the indicator, click both.
You will need to login to your Google account and copy a token into the Grive setup, otherwise, very simple!